# Trouble Executing Batch Get in AWS Appsync with Dynamo Db

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I have trouble executing Batch Get in app sync. This is my following resolvers.

**Request mapping template.**

```
#set($ids = [])
#foreach($id in ${ctx.args.topicIds})
   #set($map = {})
   $util.qr($map.put("topicId", $util.dynamodb.toString($id)))
   $util.qr($ids.add($map))
#end

{
 "version" : "2018-05-29",
 "operation" : "BatchGetItem",
 "tables" : {
    "Topic": {
        "keys": $util.toJson($ids),
        "consistentRead": true
    }
 }
}
```

**Response Mapping Template**

```
$util.toJson($ctx.result.data.Topic)
```

This is how I give the query

```
 query listStudentBookmarkedTopics {
   listStudentBookmarkedTopics(
     topicIds: [ "503", "501" ]
   ) {
     topicId
   }
 }
```

But I am getting null results

```
 {
  "data": {
    "listStudentBookmarkedTopics": [
      null,
      null
    ] 
  }
}
```

**This is how my table looks like**

[image]

**This is Cloud watch logs**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Fixed it by applying appropriate permissions. If you created new IAM role it doesn't grant `batch*` permissions by default. From AWS docs:

> Like other resolvers, you need to create a data source in AWS AppSync and either create a role or use an existing one. Because batch operations require different permissions on DynamoDB tables, you need to grant the configured role permissions for read or write actions:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
        "dynamodb:BatchWriteItem"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:dynamodb:region:account:table/TABLENAME",
        "arn:aws:dynamodb:region:account:table/TABLENAME/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

You either can attach a new policy or just add `"dynamodb:BatchGetItem"` on existing one in IAM dashboard.
`

Answer (score 0):

what does your DynamoDB Table look like? Is `Topic` the name of the table? What is the primary partition key defined on it? I need additional details to help you with this.

Alternatively, please turn on CloudWatch logs for your API (you should be able to do this via Console -> under Settings page for your API). Try to run your query again, and see what is the resolved Request and Response templates for this path. That should provide you additional details.

Comment: I have included the table. I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks, could you also post the resolved Request/Response mapping log entries from CloudWatch logs, for the path [query, listStudentBookmarkedTopics]?

Comment: I have added the cloud watch logs. I am getting insufficient error for resources or something.

Comment: Looks like a resolver is not attached to the query field. Can you check that? Also, please confirm if you have `ALL` selected for the log settings.